# What the difference in firebase-core and firebase-analytics libraray?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Google recently released new verison of Firebase. So I was trying to migrateto Firebase analytics.

So what is the difference between these libraries

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
```

and

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
```

I found that core is for analytics too.
So whats the difference? Which should I use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently there is no difference.

The `firebase-core:9.0.0` has no classes and resources in the aar file and contains the `firebase-analytics` as you can check in the pom file.

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-core</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-analytics</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also in [the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) you can find:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0 ->> Analytics
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on google [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) you don't need firebase-core anymore:

> You no longer need to add the Android library
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core. This SDK included the Firebase SDK
>   for Google Analytics. Now, to use Analytics (or any of the Firebase
>   products that require or recommend the use of Analytics), you need to
>   explicitly add the Analytics dependency:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently since June 12, 2018 declaring *com.google.firebase:firebase-core* is required to use any of the Firebase features ([firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_may_23_2018](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_may_23_2018)). 
According to [firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries) , *firebase-analytics* is not even a public module, and is probably not intended to be used directly.