# Migration from Google Analytics to Firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Since Google officially stated the sunset for Google Analytics in October 2019, I was wondering if there is an actual Migration plan already out as I can't seem to find any official source yet?

Hope I'm not asking the obvious. 
Any heads up is welcome

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a 13 page PDF](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/QZuv6pLepAgDzg8G7PVZ1hWDgBd28t7I5GWF) linked from [this Firebase Help article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9447593) with the title

> Google Analytics for Firebase - Migration Guide [from legacy Google
>   Analytics App views - GA SDK]

that may be what you're after. It's unfortunately not a quick and easy process, it looks like the guide is more to help you in converting your existing GA approach to a Firebase one than actually migrating.

Intro:

> This guide is written for users familiar with Google Analytics (web and app analytics solutions) who are considering new implementations or implementation updates to their iOS and Android apps. There are different migration techniques/preferences and this guide is a suggestion about how you could plan your migration.

---

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933008) is more helpful IMO.