# How move Google-Analytics to Firebase-Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

I try move GA to Firebase,but I have some problem.

GA:

```
public void Event(final String category, final String action, final String label, final long value) {
    mGoogleAnalyticsTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(category).setAction(action)
            .setLabel(label).setValue(value).build());
}
```

I try use firebase

```
public void Event(final String category, final String action, final String label, final long value) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("category", category);
    params.putString("action", action);
    params.putString("label", label);
    params.putLong("value", value);
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("ga_event", params);
}
```

I only can see "ga_event" on Firebase webside.
I can't get category ,action ,label and value information on Firebase webside.

1. Can I use this method do it?
2. How do I get category ,action ,label and value information ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37919630/4887268

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move from Google-Analytics to Firebase-Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919630/how-to-move-from-google-analytics-to-firebase-analytics)