# Use 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Although the [Firebase Get Started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and the [Analytics Get Started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) both specify inclusion of `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.X.X` for Firebase Analytics, the [build.gradle for the sample app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/analytics/app/build.gradle#L29-L36) uses the `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.4.0` library.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339619/4815718) to a related question indicates they are essentially the same.  Is there a reason to use one or the other for Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

The `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` has `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` contained. There is no difference but documentation suggests the use of the `core` to implement **Analytics**. Check previous post related to this:

[What the difference in firebase-core and firebase-analytics libraray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337834/what-the-difference-in-firebase-core-and-firebase-analytics-libraray)